# Batch - Rename Filetype and overwrite file

Tags: batch-file, overwrite, file-type

I have a batch file which is using the following code:

```
cd ..\changed
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *.txt') do (
ren "%%i" "*.xxx"
)
```

The change of filetype works great, but there is a problem when in folder changed are two files with the same name. Is there any posibility how to overwrite file with the same name using similar code? 
Thank You

Comment: I don't think i understood your question. How can there be 2 files with identical names in the same folder?

Comment: Instead of your whole `for ... ( ... )` use `ren *.txt *.xxx`

Comment: You could insert `del "%%~ni.xxx" 2> nul` before the `ren` command line...

Comment: Maybe the `A duplicate file name exists, or the file
cannot be found.` error message is the problem when `something.xxx` exists while you rename `something.txt` to `something.xxx`

Comment: Duplicate files in folder exists because I use convertor which convert some files and copy them into folder *changed*. It is possible to run this convertor many times on one file. 

Del command helped me! Thank You!